# How to add a visualforce page to the end of existing page according to a condition?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Suppose we have a custom salesforce controller and a custom visualforce page for it. at the end of the visualforce page I like to evaluate a public member variable of the controller and if it is true I like to add the contents of another visualforce page (e.g. apex/test) to the first page.

```
<apex:page controller="mycontroller">
...........
my tags and page contents comes here
...........

{!if(my_member_variable == true, attach contents of "apex/test" page to end of this page, "do nothing")}

</apex:page>
```

How can I do that?

In simple words, I am searching for a command similar to include() on PHP for visualforce.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use an [apex:include](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm) along with its rendered attribute.

```
<apex:page controller="mycontroller">
    <!-- ... -->
    <apex:include pageName="TheNameOfTheIncludedPage" rendered="{!my_member_variable}"/>    
</apex:page>
```

Incidentally. The [salesforce.stackExchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.